# How do i remove this error?

Tags: python, sframe

I am trying to count the number of times the word 'awesome' has been used in the dictionary and use that function in order to apply it on an SFrame data. but i keep getting an error stating 
-local variable 'aw_count' referenced before assignment
the code is something like this::

```
def awesome_count(word_count):
    if 'awesome' in word_count:
        aw_count = word_count['awesome']
    return aw_count;

products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def awesome_count(word_count):
    aw_count = 0
    if 'awesome' in word_count:
        aw_count = word_count['awesome']
    return aw_count;
```

You will get this error you stated if there are no **'awesome'** in **word_count**